# How to rename multiple text files in a local directory using python?

Tags: python-3.x, file-rename

I have multiple files with below naming. I would like to rename them. Please suggest.

Old names:

```
D_Punjab_12733_Config_Backup_POST_202008041532
D_Delhi_8673_Config_Backup_POST_2020080836783
D_Mumbai_112_Config_Backup_POST_374593736783
```

After rename:

```
Punjab_12733
Delhi_8673
Mumbai_112
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have written so far, and whats the problem with that code.

Comment: This function is just a small part of a big program. I am stuck with  this little chunk. And have  stripped "D_ " from filenames so far using below code, but couldn't find any way to strip rest of the strings.



for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.startswith("D_"):
        os.rename(filename, filename[2:])

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have the filepaths in the `paths` variable

```py
for path in paths:
  new_path = '_'.join(path.split('_')[1:3])
  os.rename(path, new_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for the support, but it's not working. It would be better if we split it on the basis of "_Config_Backup" at the end. Front could be split using "os.rename(filename, filename[2:]"

Comment: Change the `[1:2]` to `[1:3]` in the given answer to get your desired result

Comment: Thanks a lot Mahdi_J & DanBrezeanu for making me achieving my objective.